# Cannibal numbers with target incorrect return

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to write a function that, when given a list of numbers or string of numbers separated by commas as well as a target number, will find the number of numbers in that list that are equal to the target or can become the target.

Numbers can change by eating numbers that are smaller than or equal to them, after eating a number the larger number will have grown by 1 and the smaller number disappears.
The function checks all the numbers in the provided list so if you have [27,9,11,10,8] and your target is 12 then the function should return 3 because 11 can eat 10 to become 12, 10 can eat 9 and 8 to become 12, and 9 can eat 8 then it can now eat 10 and then 11 to become 12.

My issue is that when provided with something like [3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1] with target 4, my function returns the wrong value (value should be 9). For some reason my function does not recognise numbers that are equal as numbers that can be eaten even though in the if statement there is a ">=".

```
def cannibal(l, target):

     try:
         l = l.split(",")
         l.sort(reverse = True)
         l = list(map(int, l))
         print (l)

     except:
         l.sort(reverse = True)
         print (l)

     finally:

         eatingl = l[:]
         count = 0
         flag = True


         for i in range(0,len(l)-1):

             if l[i] > target:
                 print (l[i],"got skipped at",i)
                 continue

             if l[i] == target:
                 print (l[i],"at",i,"got added")
                 count += 1
                 continue

             if l[i] < target:

                 while flag:

                     if eatingl[i] < target and len(eatingl) == 1:
                         flag = False
                         break

                     if eatingl[i] == target:
                             (eatingl[i],"at",i,"got added")
                             count +=1
                             flag = False
                             break

                     for j in range(0,len(eatingl)):


                         if eatingl[i] == eatingl[j]:
                             continue

                         print (eatingl[i],eatingl[j])


                         if eatingl[i] >= eatingl[j]:
                             print (eatingl[i],"is eating",eatingl[j])
                             eatingl.remove(eatingl[j])
                             eatingl[i] += 1
                             break

                         if eatingl[i] > target:
                             flag = False
                             break



         print (count)
         return count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my function does not recognise numbers that are equal as numbers that can be eaten even though in the if statement there is a ">=".

There is only one `>=` in your code, and not far above it is this:

```py
                         if eatingl[i] == eatingl[j]:
                             continue
```

This line stops a number from eating an equal number.  Did you want this line to stop a number from eating itself?  If so, you need the condition above to be `if i == j:` instead.

There are, however, a few other problems with your code:

- Once you've found one number that can reach the target, you need to reset the list for the next number.  You already have a line `eatingl = l[:]` which will do this, but it's outside the `for i in ...` loop.  Move it inside.
- Secondly, under the line `if eatingl[i] == target:` you have the following line.

  ```
                       (eatingl[i],"at",i,"got added")
  ```

  This puts together a tuple with four items in it and then throws it away because nothing is done with it.  I'm guessing you are missing a `print` here.
- Thirdly, your variable `flag` is set to `True` before the `for i in ...` loop starts.  As soon as this variable gets set to `False`, the `while` loop never gets entered again, so your program will never find any more than one cannibal number.  Instead, move the line `flag = True` to immediately above the `while` loop.
- Next, when a number gets eaten you remove it from the list `eatingl`.  This doesn't cause a problem when `j > i`, but it does when `j < i`, because removing the number at index `j` will move the number at index `i` to index `i - 1`, after which you then increment the number at index `i`, which might be a different number.

  Adding to or removing items from a list that you are iterating through often causes problems.  Instead of removing the numbers it is simpler to replace them with a placeholder value such as `0`, `-1` or `None`.  You would need to be sure that you don't attempt to eat a number that has already been eaten, and you can do this by checking that `eatingl[j]` isn't the placeholder just before checking whether `eatingl[i] >= eatingl[j]`.
- If your program gets to the end of the `j` loop without `break`ing out of it, then there aren't enough other numbers that `eatingl[i]` could eat to reach the target.  In this situation you would want to `break` out of the `while` loop.  The easiest way to do this is to add an `else` clause to the `for` loop:

  ```py
                       else:
                           print("Could do no more for", eatingl[i])
                           flag = False
                           break
  ```

  The `else` line in the above should line up with the `for j in ...` line.  A `for` loop can have an `else` block, and the code in the `else` block runs if the code in the `for` loop did not `break`.
- Finally, your `i` loop should be `for i in range(0,len(l)):` rather than `for i in range(0,len(l)-1):`.  If you have a unique smallest number, as in your example `27,9,11,10,8` then this isn't a problem: a unique smallest number cannot eat any other numbers so skipping it doesn't do any harm.  But in your example 3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1, where the smallest number is 1 and there are three of them, each of the 1s can eat the other two 1s and then a 2 to become a 4.

I made these changes to your code and it gave me the output I expected it to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your explanation of each problem was great. My only problem was understanding the part about using a placeholder value, if I were to set the placeholder to 0 then wouldn't the number just eat it? What placeholder could I use in this case? EDIT: I set the placeholder value as the target+1, this way it will skip it

Comment: @Ktass99: sorry for not being clear about the placeholder.  In the line `if eatingl[i] >= eatingl[j]` you would add an extra check that `eatingl[j]` isn't the placeholder value.  For example, if you were using `0` as the placeholder, it would be `if eatingl[j] != 0 and eatingl[i] >= eatingl[j]`.